# Minecraft fazer o jogador conectar ao jogo

Tags: java, socket

Olá eu tenho tentado fazer o cliente conectar ao servidor com sockets este site tem um explicação http://wiki.vg/How_to_Write_a_Client#Login mas eu não consigo achar uma maneira de fazer login ja tentei `out.writebyte`, `out.writeInt`, etc.. alguem sabe como fazer isso que estão a explicar?

Tenho este codigo ate agora:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    new Main();
}

public Main(){
    try {
        InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 25565);
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(address, 1000);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.writeUTF("0x02");
        out.writeUTF("0xCD");
        //..... nao faz nada

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

EDITADO:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 25565);
    System.out.println("Creating socket to '" + "localhost" + "' on port " + "25565");
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    socket.connect(address, 2000);
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    out.writeByte(0x02);
    out.flush();

    System.out.println(in.read()); //read int, repost é -1

    byte answer = in.readByte(); //erro, aqui diz java.io.EOFException
    if (answer != 0xFD) {
        System.out.println("server says:" + in.readByte());
    }

    System.out.println("Successfully sent 0x02 & received 0xFD");

    out.writeByte(0xCD);
    out.flush();    
    System.out.println("Connection was completed successfully");
}
```

Comment: tem certeza que a autenticacao no servidor esta desligada? alem disso, depois de enviar '0x02' voce nao esta aguardando um '0xFD'.

Comment: sim a autenticaçao está desligada, e eu nao sei muito bem como e que os packets funcionam por isso que estou a pedir ajuda aqui no stack overflow

Comment: alguem sabe a resposta?

Comment: Não me lembro bem como *sockets* funcionam, mas você não precisava fazer `out.flush()` para "obrigar" os dados a irem? (eles podem estar parados no *buffer*...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vejo ao menos 3 problemas [em potencial] com seu código:

1. Quando a documentação linkada diz para "enviar um 0x02", ela provavelmente quer dizer o *byte* `0x02`, não a *string* `"0x02"`. Troque seu código para:

   ```
   out.writeByte(0x02);
   ```

   (não se preocupe em converter o `int` para `byte`, o método [`writeByte`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeByte%28int%29) aceita um `int` mesmo, por conveniência...)
2. Após enviar esse byte, "dê descarga" (*flush*) na *stream* para garantir que os dados realmente foram; eles podem estar parados em algum *buffer*:

   ```
   out.flush();
   ```

   (Não tenho certeza se esse passo é mesmo necessário com o `InputStream` retornado por um `Socket`, mas na ausência de informações em contrário eu diria que sim.)
3. Antes de enviar o próximo byte, espere o servidor dar sua resposta, como [apontado por Olimon F. nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57010/minecraft-fazer-o-jogador-conectar-ao-jogo#comment117519_57010):

   ```
   byte resposta = in.readByte();
   if ( resposta != 0xFD ) {
       // O servidor retornou algo inesperado, faça alguma coisa a respeito
   }

   out.writeByte(0xCD);
   ...
   ```

   Se você não se interessa por essa resposta, você pode ignorá-la, mas não sei qual seria a consequência de enviar o `0xCD` antes de obtê-la (o servidor pode inclusive descartar esse dado, então não é uma boa ideia enviá-lo mais cedo).